# In terms of battery usage, which distro is more efficient between Lubuntu and Xubuntu?

Tags: 11.04, power-management, xubuntu, lubuntu

Installing both on the same laptop without doing nothing more than the normal install, which one consumes less battery power at the end and makes the laptop last a little bit longer than the other, Lubuntu (LXDE) or Xubuntu (Xfce). Assuming that both will receive the same activities on the same laptops for the same amount of time.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Phoronix [reported some Power and Memory comparison results](http://www.phoronix.com/scan.php?page=article&item=linux_desktop_vitals&num=1) for Gnome, LXDE (Lubuntu) & XFCE (Xubuntu).

The conclusions where that LXDE did comparatively better in reducing power consumption compared to both Gnome and XFCE.

Comment: Phoronix "benchmarks" are very questionable as there is no analysis of the numbers and what they might mean. That one in particularly awful as it only uses **one** machine, **one** distro and **one** version of the software in question to claim a broad comparison of resource usage between DEs. No information is even given how many times the experiment was repeated - are the results repeatable, or just a fluke? Who knows?

Comment: hmmm - I think you should discuss this with Michael Larabel - I'm sure you'll get a robust response to questioning his testing methodology.

Comment: Thanks fossfreedom. I find it rather odd since I always check phoronix every day. Must have been the day I went to the other galaxy to fight an alien invasion.

For the reply about scottl good questions. Maybe answers can be found in their forums or answered by the phoronix team (or maybe already posted but you were also with me fighting aliens with plasma guns and duke nukem.

Comment: I've tried raising these issues and asking on the forums but they're so full of Phoronix fanboys that rational discussion is difficult. Phoronix crappiness is not controversial (https://lkml.org/lkml/2010/5/31/415); even core kernel devs like Ted Ts'o have described the site as 'idiotic' (http://lkml.org/lkml/2010/6/1/4)

Comment: There's nothing wrong with Phoronix methodology, when comparing desktop enviroments they should and did test on the same distro and same hardware. Sure it would be great to have more tests, but they very often do not have the manpower to do that. As for lack of comments - the numbers speak for themselves.

Comment: The Phoronix benchmarks mentioned don't appear (to me) to show a substantial difference.  Any difference in those benchmarks could be attributed to a dozen other causes.